# Remove white space and extra decimals in filename

Tags: php, preg-replace, decimal, filenames, space

I've tried both of these but they don't quite work. I need to remove any spaces and/or extra decimals (except the last obviously) in the file name.

This removes the extra decimals fine, but still leaves the whitespaces:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', $filename);
```

Is there a solution that does both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/[\. ](?=.*\.)/', '', $filename);
```

The key is that you want to include both the decimal and the space in the character set at the beginning.

Incidentally, this is a good tool for testing your regex attempts quickly: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php